# How to float images left and right without text wraps

Tags: html, css, image, css-float

I have this image floated to the left of text working fine using the css below. How would I repeat the effect for an image to the right of text on the same page. Do I need a clearfix between the left and right for example?

Thanks

```
.innercontent {
padding: 0 0 0 185px;
position: relative; 
text-align:justify;
}

.innercontent img {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

<div class="innercontent">
     <img src="/media/18/tractor_150.jpg" alt="tractor" width="150" height="107" />
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make the css more specific such as:
What i do is create master super class: .fl and .fr for float left and float right and just apply it as i go makes my code cleaner and easy to follow when they see it through out the html document.
    .innercontent img.fl{
    padding: 0 0 0 185px;
    position: relative; 
    text-align:justify;
    }

```
.innercontent img {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

<div class="innercontent">
     <img src="/media/18/tractor_150.jpg" alt="tractor" width="150" height="107" />
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....</p>
</div>
```

just post to this if wasn't clear :D

Comment: here is a jsfiddle to play around with i have popluated it with some thing that seems to do what you want:
http://jsfiddle.net/ctcET/

Answer (score 0):

I would just float both elements to the left. This will cause both elements to site side-by-side.

[HTML]
(Img on left)

```
<div class="innercontent">
   <img class='floatLeft' />
   <p class='floatLeft'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....</p>
   <div class='cleaner'></div>
</div>
```

(Img on right of text)

```
<div class="innercontent">
    <p class='floatLeft'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....</p>
    <img class='floatLeft' />   
    <div class='cleaner'></div>  
</div>
```

[CSS]

```
.cleaner{clear: left; line-height: 0; height: 0;} 
.floatLeft{float: left;}
```

The cleaner is used to return the next element back to the left after a floated element. I always put this after I float elements. It's usually works fine without it, but I tend to float elements with other "no floated" elements inside.

Also in the css, you may have to specify the img directly to float. I'm not sure the exact syntax but something like ...

```
.floatLeft>img{float: left;}
```